# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError on comments scaffold for blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the comments scaffold to make a blog, but I am getting an error. This attribute used to work with rails 3.2, but with 4.0, it stopped working. Here is the extracted source:

```
 def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
**@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])**
respond_to do |format|
if @comment.save
```

The line marked with asterisks is the highlighted line that is not working. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 introduced [Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). You are required to explicitly mark the attributes as safe when passing them to a mass-assignment function (in this case build).

Rails 3 used a different approach where you could define the `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` in the view.

With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted. This means you'll have to make a conscious choice about which attributes to allow for mass updating and thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed.

```
@post.comments.build(comment_params)
```

where `comment_params` is defined as

```
def person_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(...) # List here whitelisted params
end
```

Make sure to read the following resources

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters
- https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not that tech savvy in ruby on rails. What exactly should I do to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I have read the articles, but I don't understand them. I really need a quick fix.

Comment: Are you going to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add **gem 'protected_attributes'**  to your Gemfile, run bundle install, and it should work.

```
#Gemfile

gem 'protected_attributes'
```

documentation here:
https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes

---

but i think you should follow Simone Carletti answer.